# Estimate the subgroup order of group of units in finite algebra in GAP

Tags: group-theory, gap

Let $G$ be a finite group $p$-group and $FG$ be a modular group algebra of $G$.
Is there any way to estimate the order of subgroup generated by two or more elements of $U(FG)$, where $U(FG)$ is the group of units of $FG$? For small groups it extremely easy.
The larger group and field, the more difficult this exercise is.

**Example.**

- Easy.

```
gap> G := QuaternionGroup(8);;
gap> F := GF(2);;
gap> FG := GroupRing(F, G);;
gap> UFG := Units(FG);;
gap> Order(Subgroup(UFG, [Random(UFG), Random(UFG)]));
32
gap> Order(Subgroup(UFG, [Random(UFG), Random(UFG)]));
8
```

- A little bit more difficult.

```
gap> G := OneSmallGroup(2^9);;
gap> F := GF(2);;
gap> FG := GroupRing(F, G);;
gap> FG_Teta := Embedding(G, FG);;
gap> Group([Random(G)^FG_Teta + Random(G)^FG_Teta + Random(G)^FG_Teta, Random(G)^FG_Teta]);; 
gap> Order(Group([Random(G)^FG_Teta + Random(G)^FG_Teta + Random(G)^FG_Teta, Random(G)^FG_Teta]));;
gap> Order(Group([Random(G)^FG_Teta + Random(G)^FG_Teta + Random(G)^FG_Teta, Random(G)^FG_Teta])); 
16384
gap> Order(Group([Random(G)^FG_Teta + Random(G)^FG_Teta + Random(G)^FG_Teta, Random(G)^FG_Teta]));
32768
gap> Order(Group([Random(G)^FG_Teta + Random(G)^FG_Teta + Random(G)^FG_Teta, Random(G)^FG_Teta]));
2048
```

---

My main goal is to bypass the step of calculating the exact order of a subgroup and replace it with a logical condition, in which I will determine whether the order of the subgroup is not less than.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you convert to a matrix representation, you can work in a matrix group and that is much faster:

```
gap> bas:=Basis(FG);
CanonicalBasis( <algebra-with-one of dimension 512 over GF(2)> )
gap> H:=(Group([Random(G)^FG_Teta + Random(G)^FG_Teta + Random(G)^FG_Teta, Random(G)^FG_Teta]));
<group with 2 generators>
gap> mats:=List(GeneratorsOfGroup(H),x->List(bas,y->Coefficients(bas,y*x)));;
gap> HM:=Group(mats);
<matrix group with 2 generators>
gap> Size(HM:cheap);
32768
```

The use of the `:cheap` option in the last command will stop GAP from trying to improve the degree of the permutation representation that is used internally -- doing so might help if you do further calculations in the group.

If the group gets even larger, one can use the `recog` package (with the caveat that this is so far a result that is probabilistic with a small chance of error):

```
gap> U:=Units(FG);
gap> mats:=List(GeneratorsOfGroup(U),x->List(bas,y->Coefficients(bas,y*x)));;
gap> HM:=Group(mats);;
gap> Size(RecognizeGroup(HM));
670390396497129854978701249910292306373968291029619668886178072186088201503677\
3488400937149083451713845015929093243025426876941405973284973216824503042048
```

Comment: Extremely useful. Would you share some information internals on `:cheap` option?

Comment: The code for matrix groups calculates a permutation action on vectors and then calls `SmallerDegreePermutationRepresentation` in the hope of getting a smaller degree. (This is worth doing, if you want to do more with the group.) The option `cheap` limits the amount of effort spent on reducing the permutation degree, since you only asked abouyt the size.